# SQL, choosing maximum values from another table

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

This one I've been spending the last hours on. Still haven't found an answer so I figured I'd ask.
I have two tables:

```
Country - Code, Name, Populaion.
City - CountryCode, Name, Population.
```

The Foreign key is the CountryCode which response to country.Code.

I'm trying to find the most populated city in each country, where the output is the name of the country and the city. I know this could be done with Max(), but I'm having a struggle limiting my table to showing all the countries name and showing onle the name of the most populated city.

```
SELECT country.name, city.name, MAX(city.Population) 
FROM city
LEFT JOIN country
ON city.CountryCode=Country.Code
GROUP BY city.name, country.name, city.population
ORDER BY city.population DESC;
```

This only gives me all the countries and all the cities. Could anyone help me narrow it down so it only shows every countries name but with their largest city?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first the max population in each country and then join it with the city table to know which city it belongs to. After that, join it with the country table to get the required result.

```
select co.name,
    ct.name,
    ct.population
from (
    select c1.*
    from city c1
    join (
        select countryCode,
            max(population) population
        from city
        group by countryCode
        ) c2 on c1.countryCode = c2.countryCode
        and c1.population = c2.population
    ) ct
join country co on ct.countryCode = co.code;
```

Another way of finding max in group using left join:

```
select co.name,
    ct.name,
    ct.population
from (
    select c1.*
    from city c1
    left join city c2 on c1.countryCode = c2.countryCode
        and c1.population < c2.population
    where c2.countryCode is null
    ) ct
join country co on ct.countryCode = co.code;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It did what it should, but I'm quite new to SQL, so I don't understand the co, ct, and c1, and c2. Could you please tell me what these are?

Comment: @AleksanderSimmersholm - These are called table/query aliases. You can use them to refer to column like `co.column_name` instead of typing a full table name like `country.column_name`

Comment: I see, but could you help me with something else? If you were going to use an >= ALL statment instead, how would you use it?

Comment: @AleksanderSimmersholm - Do you mean use to it get the max value per group? i.e. max population per countryCode?

Comment: Yes, err, kind of. The same as above would be what I'm trying to do, but instead of using MAX(), rather use the  >= ALL statment.

Comment: @AleksanderSimmersholm - Added the alternate solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! You've done immensely!